# How to deploy a common library in Websphere?

Tags: websphere, websphere-8

I'm just learning Websphere 8.5 and would like to know what is the simplest way to add a library, such as iText library so that it's available to all applications running on WAS.
I can see that both a Shared Library option is available in the Admin console and a some more advanced thing like "Business Level Application" which is made up of several assets. 
What is the correct approach to achieve my goal ? 
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You should not develop your applications with implicit dependencies which are in fact explicit. If the dependency is crucial for your application, it should be somehow marked as such.

With that said, there are two approaches in WebSphere - a shared library or OSGi bundle.

For the shared library concept, read [Associating shared libraries with applications or modules](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v8r5/topic/com.ibm.websphere.nd.multiplatform.doc/ae/tcws_sharedlib_app.html).

If you use OSGi to develop your application(s), I'd recommend declare the dependencies in Application-Content of APPLICATION.MF and have them available in [Internal or External bundle repositories](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v8r5/topic/com.ibm.websphere.osgi.doc/topics/ta_admin_obr_int_console.html).

I don't think BLA applies in your scenario, but would not be surprised to see how wrong I am.

p.s. Wonder why the question is tagged as websphere-7 since it refers to WebSphere 8.5?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Well as a matter of fact I've tagged it as webpshere-7 since I couldn't find a webpshere-8 tag :)